# RSS feed from Linked In

Tags: drupal-7, rss, linkedin-api

Is it possible to get RSS feed from Linked In. Google says that it is not :

- http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1277/~/rss-feed-for-network-updates---no-longer-supported
- http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/12/13/linkedin-will-kill-rss-support-december-19/

At the same time i see that Drupal 7 has such module that seems can get some posts from Linked In group :

- https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin_group_posts

Unfortunately i cannot figure out how to make it working and not sure whether it works at all.

**Questions:**

- is it possible to get RSS feed from Linked In?
- is there some 3rd part service that could parse Linked In and return
  XML RSS for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Linkedin](http://drupal.org/project/linkedin)Module?

This module provides integration with the LinkedIn API. At the moment it supports the following features:

Per-user OAuth authentication between LinkedIn and Drupal Post
LinkedIn status from node edit form (like the Twitter module)
Synchronise LinkedIn user profiles with a user profile tab in Drupal
For Drupal 7 it's still dev and there may or may not be any updates coming. But it would be a good place to start.